# Selecting multiple entries for the same attribute being equal to another

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I want to modify my existing SQL query, but can't get it to work how I want. 
(This is in no way homework / exam related)

I want a query that gets all map ids, map names and reward points just like it does now, but gets the maps for all different run ids rather than only once whatever the map id. Now, if there is a mapid for a user in inf_times, it will no longer be displayed in the final list. I want a map to be displayed once for every runid IF the mapid is not in inf_times for that user.

Table Structure:

```
inf_maps: mapid, mapname
inf_simpleranks_maps: mapid, runid, rewardpoints
inf_times: uid, mapid, runid
```

```
select a.mapid, b.mapname, a.rewardpoints 
from (select r.mapid, rewardpoints 
      from inf_maps r, inf_simpleranks_maps srm 
      where r.mapid 
      not in (select mapid 
              from inf_times 
              where uid = %d 
              group by uid, mapid) 
      and r.mapid = srm.mapid 
      order by rewardpoints desc) a, 
inf_maps b 
where a.mapid = b.mapid;
```

EXAMPLE

```
inf_times
uid mapid runid   
1    4     1

inf_simpleranks_maps
mapid runid rewardpoints
4       1       10
4       2       12 

inf_maps
mapid mapname
4      mapmap
```

The query should return

```
mapid mapname rewardpoints
4      mapmap     12
```

Instead, it now returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with `not exists`. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gU3nVbtiJ3zisJU6xwbH3D/0).

```
select
  im.mapid,
  im.mapname,
  ism.rewardpoints
from inf_maps im
join inf_simpleranks_maps ism
on im.mapid = ism.mapid
where not exists
(
  select
    mapid
  from inf_times it
  where ism.mapid = it.mapid
  and ism.runid = it.runid
)
```

Output:

```
| mapid | mapname | rewardpoints |
| ----- | ------- | ------------ |
| 4     | mapmap  | 12           |
```

Comment: Thank you! The ways of SQL are still unknown to me, but this made everything just a little bit clearer and hopefully I'll be able to build future queries by myself

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is hard to follow. Based on your sample data though, the following query would produce the results that you  expect:

```
select  m.*, r.rewardpoints
from inf_maps m
inner join inf_simpleranks_maps r on r.mapid = m.mapid
where not exists (
    select 1 from inf_times t where t.mapid = m.mapid and t.runid = r.runid
)
```